# How to sort file names with Go Programming Language?

Tags: go

In my Go project, I need to sort the `.json` files and to display their name on the terminal when I'm running this command on the terminal `go run main.go`.

I coded a program which displays all the files in the folder, but I need to sort the `.json` file.

My code is the following :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "bytes"
    "io"
)

func main() {

    if os.Args[1] == "display-json-name" {
        //reads the directory name and returns a list of directory entries
        dirname := "." 

        f, err := os.Open(dirname)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        files, err := f.Readdir(-1)
        f.Close()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        for _, file := range files {
            fmt.Println(file.Name())
        }
    }
```

How can we sort just the different `.json` files?

And the hierarchy of my project is : 
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried to achieve this?

Comment: @Adrian `if filepath.Ext(path) == ".go" {
    return nil
}`

Comment: @shtb2708  That excludes .go files.  The question says that you want .json files only.  Please clarify what you are after.

Comment: That filters out the `go` files, but what have you done to try the sorting you're asking about? Have you made any attempt or done any research that you can show?

Comment: @ThunderCat yes that exclude go file, I thought if I exclude go file I can just display the .json file

Comment: @Adrian I gave the code I tried to  achieve. My way of thinking, it was if I exclude the .go files from my folder, I can just display the .json files....

Comment: @ThunderCat my intent is to display exclusively the .json on the terminal, and I tried to display exclusively the different .json files on the terminal by excluding the other files

Comment: Use `filepath.Ext(path) == ".json"` to determine that a file has the .json extension.

Comment: That has nothing to do with sorting though - your question mentions sorting several times. Can you clarify? Are you trying to sort or just filter?

Comment: you right the exact word is filter @Adrian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on comments, it appears that the question is "How to print files where the file has a .json extension".   Here's the code:

```
if os.Args[1] == "display-json-name" {
    //reads the directory name and returns a list of directory entries
    dirname := "."

    f, err := os.Open(dirname)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    files, err := f.Readdir(-1)
    f.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        if filepath.Ext(file.Name()) == ".json" {
            fmt.Println(file.Name())
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Handle all legal cases, for example, ".JSON",  ".json", and so on. Replace `filepath.Ext(file.Name())` with `strings.ToLower(filepath.Ext(file.Name()))`. https://play.golang.org/p/7phdmYH0Rms

Answer (score 1):

https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    files, err := ioutil.ReadDir(".")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file.Name())
    }
}
```